# Renormalized electric charge(coupling to photon) of fermions are universal?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

1-loop correction(figure below) to a vertex where fermions couples to a photon is evaluated in Matthew Schwarz's textbook eqn (19.57)
[image: 3-point function]

$$i\mathcal{M}=iF_2(p^2)\frac{\sigma^{\mu\nu}}{2m} + i\gamma^\mu (1+f(p^2))$$

where
$$f(p^2) = \frac{e^2_R}{8\pi^2}\int^1_0 dx\hspace{0.5mm}dy\hspace{0.5mm}dz\hspace{0.5mm}\delta(x+y+z-1)\cdot\\
\cdot\left[\ln{\frac{z\Lambda^2}{(1-z)^2m_R^2-xyp^2+zm_\gamma^2}}+\frac{p^2(1-y)(1-x)+m_R^2(1-4z+z^2)}{(1-z)^2m_R^2-xyp^2+zm_\gamma^2}\right]$$

where
$\Lambda^2, m_\gamma, m_R$ are cut-off scale and dressed photon mass (to deal with IR divergence) and mass of fermion in the loop.
Although I didn't complete the integral yet, it appears that the result can depend on $m_R^2$. In such cases, will fermions with different mass have different (renormalized) coupling to photon?

If that is true, what will happen if $m_R$ is so heavy or so light?